# Is there a compact set which is not Jordan measurable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

Is there a compact set which is not Jordan measurable? Intuitively, the answer seems like there is no such set but I could not find a proof anywhere. Does anyone know of a proof or a counter example?

Comment: [*Jordan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Jordan), not Jordon.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a Fat Cantor Set? I think that would work since the boundary has positive measure. For example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I have heard of the Cantor Set before but not the Fat Cantor Set. Is there anything online that you recommend to study it in more detail?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of an online resource that focuses specifically on the Fat Cantor Set. I'm sure it's mentioned in online resources regarding measure theory (which I can help you find if you like). I believe fat cantor sets are mentioned in Folland's book: http://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Techniques-Applications-Mathematics/dp/0471317160

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if you know of a good online resource in measure theory. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One resource I have used is http://www.metu.edu.tr/~eduard/TEACH/GC/MeasureTheory_II/MTLI.pdf
I'm not sure if it's completely what you're looking for. I would happy to give other resources.